# lexical dispersion-plot with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, categorical-data

I need to plot a graph (of which I am not sure, if it has a specific name: some call it (lexical) "dispersion"-plot ([NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch01.html)), others "barcode" ([matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/barcode_demo.html))). I have a text, which I split in words and I want the graph to draw a thin line every time the word appears in the text. I want to do this with the *matplotlib* in *python3*. (The post "[Lexical dispersion plot is seaborn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43771135/lexical-dispersion-plot-is-seaborn)" is very similiar to my question, but it uses `stripplot` from *seaborn*, but I want to do it with *matplotlib*.)

I wrote a code, but it needs an unbelievable amount of time to draw it. My question is, how to improve this code or how to make it right in the first place. Here is a MWE:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
text = open("file.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8").read()
words = re.split("\W", text.lower())
WORD = "rabbit"
x = [i for i in range(0,len(words))]
y = [1 if w == WORD else 0 for w in words]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(x, y, width=0, edgecolor="red")
ax.set_xticks([])
ax.set_yticks([])
```

[image: example dispersion- or barcode-plot]

Comment: The code seems correct. The time it takes for your program to run will surely depend on how large the file you read in is. Concerning the drawing, you may consider using [`plt.vlines`](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.vlines) instead of bars.

Comment: You can [time](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) your code to see if (for instance!) it's splitting the text that takes longer, or testing for "Rabbit", or the plotting.

Comment: Thanks @ImportanceOfBeingErnest ! With the plt.vlines-function it is far more faster!  ('Instant' output!) It would be my answer of choice if I could mark it as such.

Comment: Since (a) this was only a guess from my side, (b) I cannot test it and (c) I'm not really in need for rep. points, I would suggest that you answer your own question with a [mcve] that shows the solution. You may then accept it in 2 days, such that the question is solved. As an argument for why `vlines` is faster: A line consists of only two points instead of 4 points for a bar; plus a BarCollection has some more attributes to consider at draw time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comment of @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I post a MWE, that is working much faster, than the code posted in the question.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import re
#text = open("file.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8").read()
text="""There was nothing so very remarkable in that;
        nor did Alice think it so very much out of the way
        to hear the Rabbit say to itself, Oh dear! Oh dear!
        I shall be too late! …; but when the Rabbit actually
        took a watch out of its waistcoat-pocket …"""
words = re.split("\W", text.lower()) # split into words
words = [w for w in words if w != ""] # remove empty elements
WORD = "rabbit" # define word to search for

x=list()
for i in range(0,len(words)): # for every word in text
    if words[i] == WORD: # check if word is word we are searching for
        x.append(i) # if so, append its position to variable x

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.vlines(x, 0, 1, edgecolor="red") # <-- ANSWER
ax.set_xlim([0, len(words)]) # set the lower and upper limits of graph
ax.set_xlabel('narrative time')
ax.set_xticks([0],minor=True) # turn off: ax.set_xticks([])
ax.set_ylabel(WORD) # turn off by droping this line
ax.set_yticks([])
fig.set_figheight(1) # figure height, see also fig.set_figwidth()
```

[image: tokens dispersion, example plot]

A possible argument for beeing much faster, than the 'same' output with `plt.bar()`, could be, that a bar-plot has more attributes to consider at draw time (see comment of @ImportanceOfBeingErnest).